# How to copy value from one column to another on Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Is there any formula or script to copy only values (not formulas) from one column to another?. I don't want to use CTRL + SHIFT + V because I need this to be automatic. For example:

```
Column A  Column B
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

All the values of column A are calculated with an array formula, I need that everytime that column A has a new record the value passes to column B for ever, so if the value or formula in column A is deleted the copied value remains in column B, is it possible to do this?

Please any help!

Comment: possible with script or macro

Comment: thank you, yes I think that but I can't find some scrip to do exactly that

Comment: see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131935/186471

Comment: You could do a trigger to check for new values. It could run each few minutes, hours or days. Would that fit your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to

- copy values from one column on a google sheet to another column on the same google sheet

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please consider this as one of many possible ways of solving your problem.

**Flow:**
1. Get active sheet
2. Get active range (column)
3. Paste values into the range (column)

**Sample Script:**

```
function copyvalues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()); //Explore the various getRange functions
  const va = rg.getValues();  //Explore Arrays if you are not familiar with it
  va.forEach(function(r,i){
    sh.getRange(i+1,2).setValues(r[0]).setNumberFormat('#,##0.00');  //Use setNumberFormat if you need to format your values with two decimal places and thousands separator (if not already done so)
  })
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Difference between const and var](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Google App Script Best Practices - see using batch operations using Arrays](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: You should also use `setValues()` instead of `setValue()`. Loop the array> create a new output array with modifications or modify the input array in-place>setValues the modified array outside the loop