# Basic but tricky Copy & Paste in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, paste, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to perform a basic but deceptively tricky task in google sheets. 
I want to set up a macro activated by a button that will copy rows A, B, and E of a row and then paste values in a specific location, say J8 K8 L8 
I've tried recording macros, and editing them, but I just can't get it right. Any help is so appreciated!
Link to sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XjXtONoMR0xORWWOVmMiNH_f9JqWG52ikmnLXnGJ3bw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please show your code so far.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532891/how-to-copy-value-from-one-column-to-another-on-google-sheets/61632069#61632069) answer your question?

Comment: please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)